# Yii2 не видит класс

Tags: yii2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотел сделать API с версиями, но выдает ошибку:

```
Class api\modules\v1\Module does not exist
```

Вроде все пути верны. Что это может быть?

Comment: Везде namespace ы правильно указаны?

Comment: @Ali У Module.php `namespace api\modules\v1;`

Comment: попробуйте этот модуль подключить либо к frontend либо к backend

Comment: Имя класса совпадает? Иногда при копировании класса, можно переименовать файл, но забыть переименовать класс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас не совпадают пути basePath куда ведет, а сам класс где?
Вот, посмотрите

```
'node' => [
    'class' => 'root\modules\node\Module',
    'controllerNamespace' => 'root\modules\node\controllers\backend',
    'viewPath' => '@root/modules/node/views/backend',
],
```

namespace модуля (Module.php): root\modules\node;
namespace класса (DefaultController.php) root\modules\node\controllers\backend;

Надеюсь, это поможет вам разобраться.